# Difference not statistically significant for all parts, but significant for the total

Tags: statistical-significance

Is it possible to have a non statistically significant difference for all sub sets but a statistically significant one for the total? If so, how should this be interpreted?

**Context**
I was reading an article (in [Italian](https://www.infodata.ilsole24ore.com/2019/07/28/matematica-italiano-inglese-migliora-no-nei-test-invalsi/?utm_term=Autofeed&utm_medium=FBSole24Ore&utm_source=Facebook#Echobox=1564292982&refresh_ce=1)) about school results improvements in different regions in Italy, and for one of the disciplines the difference in results from two different years was non statistically significant when looking at each region, but statistically significant when looking at Italy as a whole.

Comment: This strongly reminds me on the Simpson paradox. Have a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox

Comment: @Semoi Interesting, I hadn't though about the Simpson paradox! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two simple explanations that occur to me:

1) Sample size is an important factor in p-value calculations. Since your sample size is by definition larger for all of Italy than it is for any constituent region, you have greater power to detect smaller effects and may therefore get significant p-values even with identical coefficient values.

2) As @Semoi points out, patterns within regions may be absent or even opposite to patterns across regions ([Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)).